# Access quality gate status from sonarqube api

Tags: code-analysis, sonarqube

### My question:

I would like to obtain the current status of the quality gate for my projects in SonarQube via the SonarQube web api, but I do not see quality gate as an available metric in the documentation. What is the best way to access this information to include in a report?

### Background:

I am using the SonarQube API to access information about project analyses. The output from the API is used to generate a weekly report. I can access the information about each project with the following SonarQube API call.

```
http://my-sonar-site/api/resources/index/?resource=$PROJECT_KEY&metrics=$METRIC_LIST
```

The metric list is populated from the SonarQube API documentation at

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+definitions

This gets me everything I want with the exception of the status of the quality gate.

### What I've tried:

- I have looked through the documentation for metrics at the above link, but failed to find quality gate status in that part of the api.
- I have also looked at the quality gate API documented at  http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation#api/qualitygates - but the quality gate API seems to be used for creating and managing quality gates and project associations rather than obtaining the current status of the gate on a per-project basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve what you want with the "quality_gate_details" metric. As an example on Nemo: http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/resources/index/?resource=org.codehaus.sonar:sonar&metrics=quality_gate_details

```
[{"id":48569,"key":"org.codehaus.sonar:sonar","name":"SonarQube","scope":"PRJ","qualifier":"TRK","date":"2014-11-30T16:13:17+0000","creationDate":null,"lname":"SonarQube","version":"5.0-SNAPSHOT","description":"Open source platform for continuous inspection of code quality","msr":[{"key":"quality_gate_details","data":"{\"level\":\"ERROR\",\"conditions\":[{\"metric\":\"blocker_violations\",\"op\":\"GT\",\"error\":\"0\",\"actual\":\"3.0\",\"level\":\"ERROR\"},{\"metric\":\"critical_violations\",\"op\":\"GT\",\"error\":\"0\",\"actual\":\"15.0\",\"level\":\"ERROR\"},{\"metric\":\"test_failures\",\"op\":\"GT\",\"warning\":\"0\",\"error\":\"\",\"actual\":\"0.0\",\"level\":\"OK\"},{\"metric\":\"skipped_tests\",\"op\":\"GT\",\"warning\":\"0\",\"actual\":\"0.0\",\"level\":\"OK\"},{\"metric\":\"coverage\",\"op\":\"LT\",\"warning\":\"\",\"error\":\"80\",\"actual\":\"81.5\",\"level\":\"OK\"},{\"metric\":\"test_errors\",\"op\":\"GT\",\"warning\":\"0\",\"error\":\"\",\"actual\":\"0.0\",\"level\":\"OK\"},{\"metric\":\"sqale_effort_to_grade_a\",\"op\":\"GT\",\"warning\":\"\",\"error\":\"0\",\"actual\":\"0.0\",\"level\":\"OK\"}]}"}]}]
```

For now, to get a full list of metrics, you can browse the "metrics" database table.
Feel free to watch https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5378 that should make the detailed list of metrics available directly on the SonarQube web interface.

Comment: unfortunately, `api/resources` API is deprecated since Sonarqube 5.4

Answer (score 40):

Since SonarQube 5.3 you can get the Qualitygate Status using the API:
    http://[sonarhost]/api/qualitygates/project_status?analysesId=[ID]

Since SonarQube 5.4:
    http://[sonarhost]/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=[key]

Comment: It is possible to get result from different branches, like:
?branch=master&projectKey=projectname

Comment: Hi Pwnstart, wondering if you know how to run it from a branch? thanks

Answer (score 1):

This curl command gets response for a special project key and branch and writes in a json file:

```
curl -u $YOUR_TOKEN: -G --data-urlencode "branch=$YOUR_BRANCH" --data-urlencode "projectKey=$YOUR_PROJECT_KEY" ${SONAR_HOST}/api/qualitygates/project_status > result.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how above api worked. It should be
curl -k -u ${TOKEN}: -G --data-urlencode --data-urlencode https://${SONAR_HOST}/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=${PROJECT_KEY}

Also you can pretty print by adding  | jq '.'