# Let quality gate violation fail incremental analysis

Tags: sonarqube

We're trying to set up a pull-request build pipeline that is triggered from Bitbucket, reports back failure when Sonarqube's code analysis reports some quality gate violation and ultimatively rejects the PR.

As far as I have read, the build breaker plugin, that should enable such a thing, [is no longer supported](http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/Sonarqube-and-Build-Breaker-Plugin-td5034703.html) in the most recent versions of Sonarqube, at least not in incremental / preview modes, since they now work database-less.

What are my alternatives for creating such a functionality? Sticking with 5.0?

Also, I figured that since quite some time Sonarqube can spit out [Text / HTML reports](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/SonarLint+for+Command+Line) for CI analysis - does this output quality gate violations as well or only all individual inspection results? Should one retrieve the former [via API then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27445567/access-quality-gate-status-from-sonarqube-api)? But I suspect this would require a full analysis, since it requires the results to be saved to the database, right?

Comment: I am voting to close the question because it's not unique to programming as [defined in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This would be a better fit for [Software Quality Assurance and Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com), or [sf]/[su] for advice regarding Bitbucket itself or its plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two Bitbucket-related plugins to analyze pull requests. One for [On Demand/Cloud](https://github.com/mibexsoftware/sonar-bitbucket-plugin) and one for [Server](https://github.com/AmadeusITGroup/sonar-stash). Each will add comments to your pull request, and the On Demand version will approve a PR with no new issues.

Regarding your second question, the Issue Reports you're referring to contain only issues. In fact, it's not possible to calculate general Quality Gate compliance from a preview/incremental analysis since such analyses look only at issues, and Quality Gates can contain conditions on tests, duplications, &etc.

Comment: Hrm... I see, so when I want to get a quality gate information out of sonarqube, I need to run a full analysis. And if I want to do that for short-living PRs, I have to run this full analysis with a custom project key and delete the project after the PR approval happened to avoid polluting my Sonarqube database, right?

Comment: Yup. Not really worth it IMO.

Comment: A huge sonar limitation if you ask me. I don't understand why someone wouldn't want to check his quality gates (e.g. coverage drop) *before* merging a pull request.