# How to check quality gate status for a project using the API?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.3, hipchat, sonarqube-api

I need to trigger HipChat notification for a project as soon as quality gate fails for a project in SonarQube. Is there a REST API for checking the quality gate status of a project. I couldn't find it under `api/quailty_gate` or `api/projects`.

I am open to other approaches of triggering a hipChat notifications as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [web service api/qualitygates/project_status](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation/api/qualitygates/project_status) has been introduced in v.5.3 to be able to get the gate status of a specified analysis (see parameter `analysisId`, which value is output during analysis). The initial goal is to be able to "[break the build](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Breaking+the+CI+Build)".

Version 5.4 added the parameters projectId and projectKey which are convenient when analysis is not known.

Note that version 5.5 will allow a SonarQube plugin to directly send a notification, for example to HipChat, when an analysis is finished. See [JIRA ticket SONAR-7488](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7488).

Answer (score 5):

You can get the quality gate status by using this REST endpoint:

```
/api/resources/index?includealerts=true&metrics=alert_status
```

which will give you an output similar to this one:

```
{
    "key": "alert_status",
    "data": "ERROR",
    "alert": "ERROR",
    "alert_text": "Major issues > 10, Files > 3"
}
```

Comment: This API is deprecated since v5.4, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36288348/6651