# How gate status for a project using the API from SonnarQube for TeamCity

Tags: sonarqube, teamcity

I want write script as Command Line in TeamCity  for break my assembly. I using SonnarQube v: 7.....

My script is:

```
set PROJECTKEY="%sonar.proj.key%"
set QGSTATUS=`"%curl.exe%" -s -u 
http://SONNAR_URL:9000/api/qualityates/project_status?projectKey=$PROJECTKEY

if "%%QGSTATUS%%" == "OK" exit 0
if "%%QGSTATUS%%" == "ERROR" exit 1
```

But request

```
http://SONNAR_URL:9000/api/qualityates/project_status?projectKey=$PROJECTKEY
```

return for example this message:

```
 "projectStatus": {
       "status": "ERROR",
       "conditions": [
           {
               "status": "ERROR",
               "metricKey": "new_security_rating",
               "comparator": "GT",
               "periodIndex": 1,
               "errorThreshold": "1",
               "actualValue": "5"
           },
           {
               "status": "ERROR",
               "metricKey": "new_reliability_rating",
               "comparator": "GT",
               "periodIndex": 1,
               "errorThreshold": "1",
               "actualValue": "3"
           },
           {
               "status": "OK",
               "metricKey": "new_maintainability_rating",
               "comparator": "GT",
               "periodIndex": 1,
               "errorThreshold": "1",
               "actualValue": "1"
           },
```

But I need, that api requst return me only status "Failed" or Error.

It's necessary for break my assembly in TeamCity

Script from hear ([Quality Gate Failure in SonarQube does not fail the build in Teamcity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52530153/quality-gate-failure-in-sonarqube-does-not-fail-the-build-in-teamcity))

not working for me, maybe because I using SonnarQube v 7...

How write correct script for TeamCity or how write correct API request, that get one word - Error or Ok

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and managed to solve with the example below. 
Hope this helps!

You have to enter this code by creating a PowerShell step in Teamcity.

```
$QGSTATUS = curl.exe -s -u yourLogin:yourPassword http://YourSonarAPIQualityGate | jq '.projectStatus.status'

if ($QGSTATUS -eq "OK")
{
 echo SUCCESS
 exit 0
}
else 
{
 echo "QUALITY GATE SONAR ERROR"
 exit 1
}
```

Comment: But this is script only not working. I see Error: The term 'jq' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, I use Runner type: "PowerShell" My Script is:      set PROJECTKEY="%sonar.proj.key%"
$QGSTATUS = %curl.exe% -s -u login:password http://sonarqube.stc:9000/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=$PROJECTKEY | jq '.projectStatus.status'

if ($QGSTATUS -eq "OK")
{
 echo SUCCESS
 exit 0
}
else 
{
 echo "QUALITY GATE SONAR ERROR"
 exit 1
}